# IIS 7 CORS issues

Tags: iis, cors

I am trying to contact an IIS webserver from a different server (i.e. CORS request).

I have configured my IIS config as:

````
    <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
        <add origin="*" allowed="true">
         <allowMethods>
          <add method="OPTIONS" />
          <add method="POST" />
          <add method="GET" />
        </allowMethods>
        </add>
    </cors>
</system.webServer>```

I then try to connect with js and see two lines in the dev tools:

Line 1:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Line 2: 

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Despite this, i get an error in chrome's dev tools that IIS doesn't get the CORS.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdKgn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYUXD.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDpO1.png
````

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add below code in the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```